# Copy a Column from a table towards another table with conditions

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update

=======
*I'm a newbie in SQL*. What i've been trying to do for a day (after going through dozens of topics here and on the internet ) is a simple task :

I want to move the column "number" from table B to table A with the condition that the number is attributed corresponding to the same name and surname as in table B.

Table AAA:

```
- [NAME], [SURNAME], [NUMBER] 

 - Bob , Dylan  , 
 - Jimi, Hendrix ,
```

etc

Table BBB:

```
- [TYPE] [AGE] [TOWN] [NAME] [SURNAME] [NUMBER]
- Guitarist , 95 , Denver , Bob , Dylan  , 45
- Guitar , 45 , Paris , Jimi, Hendrix , 47
- Dancer , 40, New-york , Jimmy, Page , 69
- etc..

UPDATE AAA A 
set A.NUMBER = B.NUMBER 
FROM A INNER JOIN BBB B on A.NAME = B.name and A.SURNAME = B.SURNAME ;
```

It does not work :(
Sorry for being a disturbing noob but I really don't know how to do.

**ERROR near A syntax ?**

Comment: Tell us what DMBS you are using

Comment: I'm using SQLitespy version 3.8.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems `sqlite` doesn't support joins on [UPDATE](http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html).

You can work around it in two ways:

IF `NAME` and `SURNAME` are `PRIMARY KEY` in `AAA` you could do:

```
INSERT OR REPLACE INTO "AAA"(NAME,SURNAME,NUMBER)
SELECT "AAA".NAME,"AAA".SURNAME,"BBB".NUMBER
FROM "AAA"
INNER JOIN "BBB" ON "BBB".NAME = "AAA".NAME 
                AND "BBB".SURNAME = "AAA".SURNAME
```

This will do an [INSERT OR REPLACE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) for every record in `AAA` with `NUMBER` from `BBB`.

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/351f8/1)</kbd>

Otherwise you can do:

```
UPDATE "AAA"
SET NUMBER = (SELECT NUMBER
                  FROM "BBB"
                  WHERE "BBB".NAME = "AAA".NAME 
                    AND "BBB".SURNAME = "AAA".SURNAME);
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8b52e/1)</kbd>

Comment: Oohh thank you very much, you rock!
Could I have use an INNER JOIN with the second option ? Does it do exactly the same thing ?

Comment: @Rsmusic. Nop. You can't have inner join on the second query, that was what you had and wasn't working. :p.